# microsoft.office.interop.word not showing up in add references

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am working on a C# project which requires reading of a word file.
I have microsoft.office.interop.word in my machine's Global Assembly Cache but still it would NOT show up in Visual Studio's Project reference list.
Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: how are you adding the reference.. are you just adding the `using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;` to the .cs file header..? if so you need to manually right click on the project reference and add it to the project as well.. perhaps since you were able to add a screen shot of your `GAC` which is not needed.. you should have added a screen shot of the `references` at the project level..

Comment: True. Thought not sure what part of reference list you wanted to see since interop doesnt come in the list of assemblies

Comment: if you added it to your project then it should be in the references if you did infact do it correctly.. my question is actually simple enough to answer... do you know how to add / consume 3rd party references or .net assemblies in your project.. you need to right click on the references node and select add reference.. from there it's pretty self explanatory..

Comment: Yes, I did a right click on reference node which pops up the list of reference that can be added (interop doesnt show up anywhere). I am not  aware of any other way to add assemblies to the project.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kh3965hw.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is a browse button in the Add References dialog that lets select an arbitrary .NET dll to add as a reference. Since you have already found the dll in the GAC, you can just copy the path into that dialog and add from there.

While it has been a while since I have worked with the interop with Office via a .NET program, there is also the COM tab in the dialog and I believe that should have a reference to Word. That may be the one that you are supposed to use.